# como realizar una busqueda en dgview mediante rango de fecha

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-forms

como puedo realizar una busqueda medieante un rango de fecha con dos datetimepicker y un boton cabe destacar que lleno mi datagridview de esta manera:

```
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Mostrar_ClientesExamen", C.conect);
    adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    gridControl1.DataSource = table;
    C.CerrarConexion();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias ayudarte con linq para realizar la busqueda dentro del grid

```
var result = from row in gridControl1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()    
                where Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["nombrecolfecha"].Value) > dtpFechaDesde.Value
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["nombrecolfecha"].Value) > dtpFechaHasta.Value
            select row;
```

con este linq obtienes una lista de rows que cumplen la condicion, despues podras recorrerlas o quizas en el linq definir un `select` y obtener una clase, esto dependera que quieras realizar con los datos obtenidos